# How can I apply browserify to my gulp file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am relatively new to gulp and browserify. For my understanding, if you could please explain how I could use browserify with my current gulp file...

As I'm using 'require' for my gulp modules, would I get any benefit using browserify? If so, how would it benefit me?

```
var sass      = require('gulp-sass'),
concat    = require('gulp-concat'),
watch   = require('gulp-watch'),
gulp    = require('gulp'),
minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
rename    = require('gulp-rename'), // to rename any file
destination = 'public/css';

// task to compile sass, minify then rename file
gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('public/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination));
});

// save typing gulp sass, and use just gulp instead
gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

// simple watch task
gulp.task('watch', function () {
   gulp.watch('public/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think `browserify` does?

At the moment, I don't see any need to include it as you are not processing/bundling any scripts.